# Matching regular expressions through the input tag in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am pretty new to PHP and pattern matching. So let me explain my problem. I have an input field as shown below:

```
<input name="usn" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="USN" pattern="[4][S][O][1-2][1-9][A-Z]{2,3}[0-9]{3}" required="required" style="text-transform:uppercase" maxlength="11">
```

In the above given pattern `4SO` is a constant which means it should be present for all inputs.

Also from what I have learned in regular expressions the pattern that I have given in the input tag should work for the following inputs:

```
4SO12CS027,
4SO12EE036,
4SO12MBA050,
4SO12MCA023,
etc.
```

But unfortunately it doesn't. I keep getting the error:

> "Please match the expected format".

Is there something wrong with the pattern I have given, or is there another way to match regular expressions like this. If so if someone show me how this is done with some example as an answer. 
Searched a lot on the Internet but didn't find anything that would satisfy me.

Comment: Not specific to your problem: A great site to learn/debug regex: https://regex101.com/.

Comment: this regex works fine for me, could be simplified to `4SO[12][1-9][A-Z]{2,3}[0-9]{3}`